Integrate Apache Knox 2.0.0 with Keycloak OpenID
I am trying to integrate Keycloak with Apache Knox using OpenID for authentication. I have modified several configuration files, including gateway-site.xml, sandbox.xml within conf/topologies, and knoxsso.xml. Additionally, I have created a new file named keycloak.xml by copying the content of knoxsso.xml, and I'm using it in the callbackUrl property.
However, despite these modifications, I'm encountering difficulties in getting the integration to work as expected. When I attempt to authenticate through Knox, I'm not redirected to the Keycloak login page.
I'm using Apache Knox version 2.0.0. Could anyone provide insight into the correct configuration steps or additional files that need to be modified to successfully integrate Keycloak with Apache Knox using OpenID?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
